# Como criar um Evento em um WebService

Tags: c#, web-service, soap, eventos

Tenho um Webservice que possui um método que grava um novo registro de entrada e atualiza a lista que contém essas entradas. Agora eu preciso que o cliente assine um evento do Webservice para que sempre que um novo registro for adicionado o evento seja disparado no cliente, para que ele possa fazer as verificações necessárias.

Comment: o que vc já fez?

Comment: A parte de receber os dados do cliente e gravar no banco de dados. É um sistema de duas frentes, uma recepção e outra supervisão. Ambas comunicam com o webservice. Eu procurei no google algumas soluções, mas são usando SignalR e todo o sistema não usa SignalR.

Comment: Está usando WebApi?

Comment: @jbueno está em Soap

Comment: E ele é `WCF` ou `ASMX`?

Comment: @jbueno ele é asmx :)

Comment: SOAP não foi feito pra isso não. No SOAP você faz requisição e obtém resposta, e nada mais. Você realmente dependerá de algo como SignalR ou um sistema de fila de mensagens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De maneira simples e sem saber muito do seu ambiente, você vai precisar criar uma espécie de *Schedule*. Um programa *console*, que tenha um *timer* ou que seja programado para rodar de tempo em tempo, observando os registros na tabela que o seu WS vai inserir. Sempre que ele encontrar algo novo lá, ele dispara a ação que você deseja.

Abaixo segue um exemplo bem genérico de como realizar um schedule para processar de tempos em tempos, de acordo com os parâmetros que você quiser.

```
    public void ProcessarRotinas()
    {
       try
        {

            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= TentativasErro; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Aqui vai toda sua regra de negócio
                        ExecutarRegra();
                        Thread.Sleep(ValordePausa * 1000);
                        break;
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {                                                
                        Thread.Sleep(ValordePausa * 1000);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Esta resposta oferece uma alternativa, já que não há comunicação de duas vias usando SOAP. Eu particularmente acho uma alternativa válida e inclusive já usei este tipo de solução (agendar no cliente uma consulta regular ao webservice já que o webservice não podia notificar o cliente).

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, no exato momento estou trabalhando em uma situação parecida, e o Schedule foi uma solução bastante viável e funcional.

Comment: @Caffé, @DeividRamon, eu não adicionei o comentário, veio direto do `From Review` o que entendi que era melhor opção adicionar um comentário ao invés de uma resposta! Da uma reformulada na resposta para ficar mais completa, pois, a pergunta em si ja é complicada! vai ganhar meu +1 assim que melhorar, Vou favoritar e aguardar a melhoria!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira entendido! Vou montar um exemplo de código e posto já. Vlw.